# Clear Application's badge Number

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, badge, tray

I have made local notification in iphone app. And set icon badge number.

All works good. But if i have two notification in tray and user clicks on clear button than notification deletes from tray.

But the badge number of icon remains same.

I want to set the badge number to zero.

Thanks.

Comment: you can set icon badge number while app launch.

Comment: Yes. But i want to reset it when user clears tray.Is it possible?

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;`

Comment: no you can not set icon badge number without opening application.

Comment: actually you can. but you need to used push notification 
[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve is only possible using the Server Notifications. You can not set badge number locally without opening the application. As you won't have any control when user clears the tray. There's no way you can set the badge count at that moment.

Comment: Is it possible to get that tray has any notification when app launches?

Comment: @Impossible no there's no way. You have no control at that moment.

Comment: so, to be clear Rushi, what you're saying is that what @Impossible wants to do is Impossible?

Answer (score 10):

use this in application didfinshlaunchingwithoptions

```
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: I want to clear badge number when you clicks on clear button on tray

Answer (score 4):

For Swift3, you can clear badge number in your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with this line :

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

You can used this line in anywhere in code if you want too.

Comment: I am having the problem that even if I delete the badge number with the above code, if a new message coming the badge number is not starting from 1, but having x+1 where x was the previous number of messages. What can be the issue here?